# Tags on CV should link back to SO search for that tag/user

Tags: feature-request, tags, jobs, cv

This seems like a natural integration. Give anyone potential hirer an easy way of accessing stuff you've written.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that I don't always answer questions with the same tags as are on my CV.  So I think a link to all my ansers would be more useful

Comment: The badges on the right side link to your SO, SF etc. profile which lists all your questions and answers.